# IE Border/Frame Appears on linked image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hyperlink, border

I was searching arround for this tiny problem.
I found nothing but border:0; which doesnt do anything at all...

I am using css reset and everything works fine in every browser except IE.
I don't have any older IE so this problem appears in IE 9 for me...

When I have an image that is linked to somewhere...

Example:

```
<a id="deviantart" href="http://deviantart.com" target="_blank"></a>

    #deviantart {
    background: url("../img/socials-sprite.png") 0 21px;
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
    position: absolute;
    }
```

And when I click on it there is an sort of border that appears ... 
Preview: http://snpr.cm/uJl3Q4.png

No idea why that thing appears and is there any solution to fix it ? It going on my nerves when I see that something is not working properly in other browsers...

Comment: #deviantart:focus { outline:none; }

or simply:

#deviantart { outline:none; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `outline` property to `none`.

```
#deviantart {
  outline: none;
}
```